# How can I assign the result of SelectSum to the variable called salary?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, promise

I want to assign the variable salary with the result of the promise. How can I do that?

````
  host: hostName,
  user: user,
  password: password,
  port: portNumber,
});

var salary;

function SelectSum (con) {
  return new Promise ((resolve, reject)=>{
    con.query("SELECT sum(salary) as sum FROM people'", (error, sum)=>{
      if (error) {
        return reject (error);
      }
      return resolve(sum);
    })
  })
}```
````

Comment: Could you share a bit more code and add some more explanation to the question? Here you can find [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You can't really de-async async code. You'll want to `await`/`then` the promise anywhere you need its value, so it's not possible to say `var salary = SelectSum(con)` synchronously (`salary` would just be an unfulfilled promise here).  Try something like `SelectSum(con).then(sum => /* use sum */)`. Please read [the canonical thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) thoroughly.

Comment: Let me know if the dupe doesn't solve it for you, after you've read it, and I can reopen for you if you can explain your problem and goal a bit more specifically.